# Bootstrap modal with angular form

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning angular and am having problems with angular forms in modals. I have a SharePoint website I am working on and I want to use a bootstrap modal containing an angular form but I seem to be having problems with scope. I have a function I use to pull data from a SharePoint list into a JSON variable I store on scope. I then use this information to populate a table on the page for display. I have a button that opens a modal to edit the items in the table. I have a function that is called to push the data back to the SharePoint list when Save Changes is clicked on the modal. My problem is that if you type into the modal and then click cancel and don't submit the changes the table on the page is still bound to the changes you made in the modal while I would like it to revert to it's original state.

I feel I should be using a directive for the modal and I may be approaching this entirely the wrong way but I am having problems getting everything working and I can't find a good example of it online so I was wondering if someone might be able to give me a hand. Below is a plunker with a simplified example of my code. Thanks for the help

http://plnkr.co/edit/duMMV4rnV9Ee8ElajBAG?p=info

I tried to turn the modal into a directive as shown below but it wasn't working for some reason.

```
myApp.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: '/_Layouts/AngularSharePoint/templates/modal.html',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$emit('updateTables', scope.postData);
        }
    };
});
```

I got a cryptic error I haven't been able to figure out

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/$compile/tplrt?p0=modal&p1=%2F_Layouts%2FAngularSharePoint%2Ftemplates%2Fmodal.html

Comment: And the actual error is: `Template for directive 'modal' must have exactly one root element. /_Layouts/AngularSharePoint/templates/modal.html`.  What does `modal.html` look like?

Comment: First, you are including the smart-table script before Angular, even though it depends on Angular. Second, you are including the smart-table script from the Github raw text source. This is a no-no that causes the script to not be interpreted  as a script at all. Use a proper CDN instead. **[See this working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DF5wr8msbtNs58eviRcn?p=preview)**.

Comment: I have fixed the smart-table issue, sorry my mistake. As for modal.html it is the modal exactly as in the example. I just pulled the html from the main page and pasted it into modal.html

Comment: The error message seems to imply that the extracted modal template HTML file may not be the same as the plunker.  Perhaps there's been a copy-and-paste error that you've missed?  If you post the content of the file someone might spot the issue.

Comment: Alright so I got the directive working. It wasn't liking a comment I had. Now my problem is that even with scope: true set my child scope is still referring to the parent scopes postItems. Apparently objects don't get deep copied into the child scope. Do you guys know of a preferred method for handling this? I was thinking about maybe using $broadcast and angular.copy to send the data to the directive unless you guys have a better idea. Feel like there should be an $apply in here somewhere but like I said I am new to this so I don't really know best practices for handling angular modals

Comment: Alright I have updated the plunker link with my now working as intended code. My goal was to have a directive with an angular form inside a modal that properly submits data back to the page and doesn't update the model if you cancel the modal. I have now accomplished this but now my question is: Is the way I accomplished this through using emit and broadcast to communicate back and forth a good way to do it? Is it the "Angular" way to do it? If not does anyone have pointers for a better way to accomplish this? Thanks!